# Doubt in understanding selection and independent events

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I have a basic doubt in following -

Selecting 2 objects from n objects = nC2
Suppose if i add condtion - **selection of 2 objects are independent of each other** then how many ways can we select 2 objects?

1st object can be selected in n ways. If selecting 2 objects are independent of each other means - 2nd object is to be selected from n objects are n-1 objects. 2nd object if picked from n-1 objects means 2nd object can not be 1st object. In that sense is 2nd object selection is dependent on 1st object(as if 1st obj selected is r then 2nd object can not be r)

If i choose 2nd object from n objects means repetion allowed?

I am confused. Please englighten me

---

sir in wiki it is given as - "If two cards are drawn with replacement from a deck of cards, the event of drawing a red card on the first trial and that of drawing a red card on the second trial are independent. By contrast, if two cards are drawn without replacement from a deck of cards, the event of drawing a red card on the first trial and that of drawing a red card on the second trial are not independent, because a deck that has had a red card removed has proportionately fewer red cards. "(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)). So when i pick a ball from a bag(without replacement), picking a ball second time, probability reduces right? so they must be dependant events right? please elaborate ....

Comment: Once you organize your thoughts, the end result is that when selecting two objects from the same bag without repetition, then which object is which is dependent on one another since knowing what the first outcome is means that that cannot be what the second outcome is.  On the other hand, selecting one object from, say, a bag of blue objects and then selecting one object from a totally different bag with red objects, the outcomes of each selection don't influence one another and so they are likely independent.

Comment: "Once you organize your thoughts, [...]" - I like that introduction 

Comment: sir please have a look at my edited comment.

Comment: i understood that if 2 events are dependent means, 1st event has an effect on probaibility of 2nd event. In another way, it is given as probability (A intersection B) = 0

Comment: Yes, when you pick without replacing the ball then the fact that the ball you chose isn't in the bag anymore affects the outcome of the next ball choice. And also yes, "dependent" can be intuitively understood that the outcome of the first influences the outcome of the second

Comment: So i have to make them independent means that either(1) replace the 1st picked ball back into the bag or (2) repetetion allowed right?

Comment: @NascimentodeCos Formally, two r.v.s $X,Y$ are independent iff $$\mathbb P(X\in A\cap Y\in B)\neq \mathbb P(X\in A)\mathbb P(Y\in B)$$ for some measurable $A,B$. See [this extensive Wikipedia article on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory))

Comment: @NascimentodeCos Isn't "repetition allowed" the same as "put it back in the bag"?